# Running PostGIS ST_ClusterWithin on large dataset?

Tags: postgis, geoprocessing, sql

I am trying to use the new ST_ClusterWithin in PostGIS 2.2 to help me aggregate building polygons that are within 5 metres. The source data has > 13million polygons.

I ran the following query on a sample and it worked brilliantly.

```
CREATE TABLE output AS SELECT ST_CollectionExtract(unnest(ST_ClusterWithin(geom, 5)), 3)::geometry(Polygon, 27700) as geom FROM building
```

however trying to run the same on the full set causes the following error.

```
ERROR:  array size exceeds the maximum allowed (1073741823)
```

Hvaing done googling on that error it seems it is causes by trying to keep the results in memory.

Does anyone know how I could improve my query to work on such a big dataset?

Comment: Can you add a `GROUP BY` clause that will reduce in size the # of polygons that are passed into the function?  For example, grouping by city?  With a large dataset, you'll also want to make sure you're on PostGIS 2.2.1 for good performance.

Comment: @dbaston am on 2.2.1, so maybe I will have to GROUP BY, however, I was hoping this method would give me the aggregated areas to then add an attribute back to the original polygons. Bit of a chicken and egg!!!

Comment: I have used a divide and conquer approach for similar problems. ie, do the cluster within for various subsets of the space, using two generate_series loops to divide into blocks, and then aggregate the output of all of these with another union or clusterwithin. Not pretty, but works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ST_ClusterWithin` and `ST_ClusterIntersecting` functions in PostGIS first collect all input geometries into a Postgres array before doing their processing.  Since the size of this array is proving to be a limitation, you can process this dataset only if you can reduce the total size of this array.  Some options for doing this:

- Use a `GROUP BY` clause to group the geometries into smaller sets before processing, using either a relevant attribute (city, county) or derived attribute (something like `(ST_XMin(geom)*1000)::int`?)
- Remove from the input any geometries that cannot be included in a cluster (`WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM buildings WHERE ST_DWithin(buildings.geom, test.geom, 5)` or similar)
- Reduce the size of the input geometries before clustering with by generalizing using `ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology` or, more radically, using `ST_Envelope`, `ST_ConvexHull`, or `ST_Centroid`.

You should be able to get a feel for how far above the size limit you are by doing a `SELECT sum(ST_MemSize(geom))` from your dataset.  I'm guessing there's some array overhead that's not captured here, but I don't know how significant that would be.

There's some discussion and development going on around enabling clustering functionality as Postgres windowing functions rather than, or in addition to, aggregate functions.  Perhaps this may allow the size limit to be overcome; it's not something I've looked into yet.

Comment: Clustering as a window function, interesting idea.

Comment: @JohnBarça feel free to test or weigh in if you're inclined!  https://github.com/postgis/postgis/pull/81

Comment: @dbaston great answer. Lots of options to try. I have used GROUP BY on a much larger sample and it worked. So going to now add a relevant attribute to their entire set and run the ClusterWithin again.

Comment: @dbaston. I think I have a legit business use case, so I will try and have a go. I could become a full-time tester just for the stuff you are turning out at the moment -- keep it up :-)